# Unrequired Boolean value from a Spring endpoint always return null

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a spring api endpoint that looks like this:

```
 public ResponseEntity<TestObj> getCounterProposals(
      @PathVariable Long testObjId, @RequestBody(required = false) Boolean status)
```

How do I send a request so that the **status** parameter gets filled up. My endpoint looks like this:

> GET /api/test/{testId}

Right now its value is always null and the testId is populated. I send the request from Postman like this:

[image]

Should I wrap the Boolean into some DTO object?

Comment: Keep in mind that a GET operation should not use a body since the GET method means retrieve whatever information. This link can help you to design your endpoint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/1230748

Comment: @dcalap it is a requirement. It must not be in the query params :)

Comment: You need to use POST to send data in  RequestBody

Comment: @btreport my requirement explicitly states it should be a GET request and the status must not be visible within the query string

Comment: @dcalap thank you, I also think the requirement is invalid. I will use a query path query parameter for now!

Comment: Ok, you can try this : https://cleanprogrammer.net/making-get-request-with-body-using-spring-resttemplate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since - as other people mentioned - having a body with a `GET` request is not conventional.
If your requirement is to use `@GetMapping` with a `status` parameter that should not be visible in the query url, maybe it's also worth taking a look at `@RequestHeaders`?

For example: `@RequestHeader("status") Boolean status`

Answer (score 0):

I have this working:

```
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name, @RequestBody Boolean status) {

    System.out.println(status);
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
}
```

And in Postman invoking the endpoint:

[image]

We are passing the `@RequestParam name` in the url `?name=David` and the boolean `status` in the body.

And is working properly.

Note that the selected tab is **Body** and the type is **JSON**. (Right after GraphQL BETA) and the passed value is `true`. Not `status - true` as `form-data` as you were passing it in your Postman request.

Comment: sure, but thats a query param and not a body. It works for me like this too and thats what i decided to use.

Comment: No, is not a query param, it's a request body. Check the `@RequestBody Boolean status` that is passed in Body tab in postman as `true` in the example.